# I want expo-print to convert my html template to pdf. and also download that pdf to my local device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I want expo-print to convert my html template to pdf. and also download that pdf to my local device. I am using react-native and expo.

```js
const downloadFromUrl = async (activityLogs) => {
  const htmlContent = createHtmlContent(activityLogs);

    const file = await printToFileAsync({
      html: htmlContent,
      base64: true
    });
    console.log(file.uri);
    await shareAsync(file.uri);
};
```

In the above code the file is only sharable but I want to download the pdf in user's device